# How do I determine number of strings of length n are palindromes using decimal digits?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling with a few of my homework problems so I thought I might ask for some help on them. Here's the question:

[image]

I'm assuming it requires $\frac{n}{2}$ to determine a number to factorialize?

I'm stumped with the length n part and not sure what to do. Anything is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a Rule for palindromes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502084/finding-a-rule-for-palindromes) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287582/how-many-n-digit-palindromes-are-there)

Comment: @RossMillikan that post makes no sense to me :/

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The situation is a bit different for even $n$ than it is for odd $n$. We do two examples, and let you handle the general case.

$n=6$: The first $3$ digits can be selected arbitrarily. Then the rest are determined. So there are $10^3$ palindromes of length $6$.

$n=7$: The first $4$ digits are arbitrary, and then the rest are determined.

Answer (score 2):

if we find first half last half are already determined
Two cases
1.n is even
First half=n/2
So for each digit you can select from 10 numbers
So number of palindromes $= 10 ^ {n/2}$

2.n is odd
Here middle digit can take any of ten digits
So number of palindromes $ = 10 ^ {{(n+1)}/2}$